# Special addition of a small matrices at particular position to a large matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

This is second and important part of question([previous one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135408/special-addition-of-a-small-matrix-to-a-large-matrix-which-will-increase-its-si)), but I will make it self contained.

We have a matrix say *MLarge* and we want to add two matrices to it at special positions, described by the conditions.
We only want to make changes at respective positions(not all), like numbers at $(i,j),$ and $(i,j+2),$ $(i+2,j)$ in *MLarge* should be changed with matrix.  e.g below

When we want to specially add two different matrices(containing variables) at different locations,
For example:

```
MLarge:= Table[i KroneckerDelta[i,j], {i, 1, 7}, {j, 1, 7}];
```

MLarge := $\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7\\
\end{array}
\right)$,

Mdiag[x_,y_] := $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & x\\
 y & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)$,
    Mnondiag[j_,k_] := $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & j\\
 k & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)$

*Mdiag* to be added to the *MLarge* on the diagonals and *Mnondiag* at $(i,j+2)$ and $(i+2,j)$.

They should look like this:
    Mfinal[x_,j_,y_,k_] := $\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
 1+0 & x & 0 & 0 & (0 & j) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 y & 0 & 0 & 0 & (k & 0) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & x & 0 & 0 & 0 & j & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & y & 0 & 0 & 0 & k & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right)$

Here, just first two(or four in the *Mfinal*) rows, indicating the case, I am interested in.
**A general formalism will be of great use, general means adding matrix or matrices(with variables as above) at any desired location.**
*Any help will be highly appreciable, as I am new I forgive for asking obvious questions.*

Comment: you mean $(i,i+2)$ and $(i+2, i)$ instead of  $(i,j+2)$ and $(j+2, i)$?

Comment: Yes, and you implemented it also. Thanks for your advice of posting it separately.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps,

```
ClearAll[insertF]
insertF[mat_, diag_, offdiag_, d_] := ArrayFlatten@ReplacePart[mat, {{r_, c_} :>
  Which[r == c, {{r, 0}, {0, 0}} + diag, Or[c == r + d, r == c + d], offdiag, True, 0]}]

insertF[MLarge, {{0, x}, {y, 0}}, {{0, j}, {k, 0}}, 2] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your attention and time. _Can you explain a little bit about the code? It will be very nice of you_. So that I can use this, to say for two or more matrices(with function) addition and at positions defined by the conditions(This what I mean general rule at the end of question, I am sorry for trouble, but it will complete the problem, as I have not posted the actual problem due to ongoing research on it, only an alias). I would like to do them by my own.

Comment: I hope it will also be helpful to others.